# PHP Excel Output <inputs> in html

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I'm currently using PHP Excel to output an excel file in html. I was wondering if it was possible to edit the source code so that instead of outputting a table, it outputs an input or textarea instead. I'm not quite sure where to begin. I'm trying to take a look at all the classes in PHPExcel and can't find where the tables are being outputted so I can change them. If anyone can help me that would be great! Thanks

```
$inputFileName = "file";   

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);    

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');

$objWriter->writeAllSheets();

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's written in `/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php`.

Maybe you could create your own writer, by extending `PHPExcel_Writer_Abstract` and implementing the interface `IWriter`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! the code for outputing the table around line 543 in the html.php file. I'm gonna try and edit it the best I can. If it doesn't work, I'll try iwriter. Thanks again! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Rather than edit the HTML Writer, copy the existing HTML.php to HTML2.php and edit that; or create an HTML2 Writer class that extends the existing HTML writer, As UrGuardian4ngel suggests, this is the whole point of the Writer abstract and Iwriter interface

Comment: Indeed. Modifying code that comes from a library or distributed package, is most of the time *not done*. I'd say, "extend the HTML writer and overwrite those methods", but they seem to be private. So copy the class, modify that. If something goes wrong, remove copy, copy original class and try again.

Comment: Got it. I'll have to rethink my strategy. Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently working on making those privates protected as part of the version 2.0 rewrite, though that won't be available till the tail end of the year; which is why copying to an HTML2.php would probably be a better (though dirtier) idea than extending

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler to create your own method to be able to add all your specific needs (image, layout, etc ..). And then share it ;)